# Django runserver in command with custom settings

Tags: python, django

I try to execute the runserver inside a command with custom settings. But the settings are not loaded:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management import setup_environ, ManagementUtility

import settings_api

setup_environ(settings_api)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Local API to retrieve realtime quotes"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if not settings_api.DEBUG:
            call_command('runserver',  '127.0.0.1:8002')
        else:
            call_command('runserver',  '0.0.0.0:8002')
```

Output is:

```
Used API settings
Used API settings
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4b1, using settings 'site.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8002/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: Your code suggest, that when it is not run in DEBUG mode, then it should be run on 0.0.0.0 ip (accessable by other computers in the network). I want to emphasize (just in case), that this is terrible idea if you want to create production server in that way. runserver is only for development. It is very dangerous and inefficient use it as production server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`runserver` forces default settings unless passed `--settings=`. Use a separate WSGI container (or even the built-in one, brought up yourself) if you want custom settings.

Comment: So pls. help me with this... how to change the code? Sorry, beeing a newbie in this section of Django

Answer (score 14):

Ignacios answer pointed me the right direction: executing the command with custom settings param solved it:

```
./manage.py command --settings=settings_api
```

More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings)