# [django]how can i change Settings.py?

Tags: django

Several configuration files exist.
If these files have different names
How do I change the settings file every time I run this command?
"python manage.py runserver"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can use any editor for changing the `settings.py` but please explain why you need to edit it every time.

Comment: This thread might help you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644848/django-runserver-in-command-with-custom-settings

Answer (score 1):

Its so simple

- read [Main Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module), its all about setting django configuration
- a shortcut for using in `runserver` command is `--settings=` and this also works with uwsgi

but if you intend to change setting without re-running the server [django-constance](https://django-constance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can add to manage.py file

```
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings_name')
```

After that run
py manage.py ----